# How do long do you manage state machine versions in AWS Step function CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk-typescript

In AWS StateMachine, according to the docs, the statemachine can publish upto 1000 versions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-state-machine-version.html

```
You can publish up to 1000 versions of a state machine. To request an increase to this soft limit, use the Support Center page in the AWS Management Console. You can manually delete unused versions from the console or by invoking the DeleteStateMachineVersion API action.
```

And I am managing my State machine in AWS CDK. Example below:

```
    // StateMachine
    const stateMachine = new sfn.StateMachine(this, 'myStateMachine', {
      definition: new sfn.Pass(this, 'DefineRepositories', { result: sfn.Result.fromString("version 1") })
    });

    // Version that always points to the latest revision by using `stateMachineRevisionId`
    const version = new sfn.CfnStateMachineVersion(this, 'Version', {
      stateMachineArn: stateMachine.stateMachineArn,
      stateMachineRevisionId: stateMachine.stateMachineRevisionId,
    });

    // When the state machine changes, the CFN does an update replacement of 'Version'
    // To prevent distruption to callers of the previous version, we need to keep it.
    version.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);
```

So, what's the best practice in managing the versions? How do you delete old version? Is it usually automated too or do you do it manually? Or would not not retain it at all?

Personally, I would prefer retaining it for `n` days.